# Which options are required for a simple Linux user?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, samba, users

I am setting up a Samba server on Ubuntu and need to create users on the server. However I am not sure which options I need to set with useradd in order for the user to work.

1. Does the samba user need a shell?
2. Does the samba user need a defined home directory?
3. Would it be a good idea to make a special group just for samba users or is it okay to use the default group?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, Samba does not use this.

   (Some other services, such as `ftp`, require a shell to ensure that the account belongs to a human. Samba uses its own account database instead.)
2. No, the home directory is not needed.

   The only exception is the special `[homes]` share, accessible at `//server/username`.
3. It depends on how you intend to manage access to files – if all users are to be treated equally, use the default group. If Samba users need additional restrictions, use a separate group. (Starting with the default might be okay.)